# Is there a way to mount a git branch (read only) on linux?

Tags: linux, git, mount

*Setup:* At work we have a git repo where our scripts are. These scripts need to be accessible on all our client linux machines (~400). The current solution is to have a file server, which regularly pulls the main branch. This then is mounted (nfs + autofs).

*Question:* Is there an easy way to mount a remote git branch read only?

I'm aware of GitFS, but this seems to be overkill. I'm looking for something lightweight, preferably in-memory, i.e. without checking stuff out on disk. I only need access to one branch, no history.

***Edit:*** To clearify this: I want to avoid pulling and cronjobs and stuff like this. Best would be something which transparently mounts a remote git repository much like a read only nfs mount.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Question:*** Is there an easy way to mount a remote git branch read only?

Yes you can do it in several ways.
Both `bundle` & `archive` are a `read-only` repository.

***`git bundle`***

```
# Clone the desired branch (-b flag)
# and pack it into a bundle with the desired name
git clone repo.bundle repo-copy -b master
```

The output of this is a single file containing the desired branch in a read-only mode since it's not a git repository.

---

***`git archive`***

similar to the above `bundle` command

```
# Create a tar archive that contains the contents of the latest commit 
# on the current branch, and 
#extract it in the /var/tmp/junk directory.
git archive --format=tar --prefix=junk/ HEAD | (cd /var/tmp/ && tar xf -)
```

Comment: @codeWizerd There is no mounting of the remote repository in your answer. Or am I missing something?